# Joomla turns all menu items to sub-sub-menu items when adding a new one

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, url, submenu

When I add a menu item, Joomla shows all menu items on all menus as if they are sub-sub-menu items, ie with a |—|— before the name in the menu manager.

This breaks the menus, or adds "root" to the URL (ie http://www.example.com/root/pagename), until I click *rebuild*, which fixes it.

This seems to have been happening since I updated to 3.5.0, though I have found previous examples of people complaining about "root" appearing in their URLs who have just been told to click *rebuild*.

I have also tried it on a second 3.5.0 site, and the problem does not happen there.

I suspect a rogue database entry somewhere. Any ideas?

Further details

- Editing a menu item does not trigger it
- "Save as copy" does trigger it
- Deleting a menu item / Clearing Trash does not trigger it
- Triggering it on a non-rebuilt menu adds two more sub-links to everything.
- The parent item remains listed as "parent item root"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to verify Assets Table, because many times that have fixed mysterous problems for me in the past. But unfortunately, there is no free tool for that.

The best assests and permission manager is commercial extension [ACL Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/acl-manager) from [Sander Potjer](https://www.aclmanager.net/), and without it I can't imagine my daily admin routine. 
It discovers & fixes issues with your Joomla assets (permissions) table you may not even be aware of and even configure the backend access to 3rd party components without basic Joomla ACL support.

Besides great tools for Permissions Management, it has fantastic Diagnostic Tools to find and fix problems with Orphan Assets, Missing Assets, Asset Issues and Admin Access Conflicts.

Comment: Thanks. I've marked as the accepted answer as that table does seem a likely cause - I found the problem is also be triggered when I install a component or create a category, and that's a shared table with all these.  I'm just going to work on a fresh install and manually copy my content rather than use ACL (as there's not much of it and I'm slightly wary of third party stuff), so if anyone finds this page with the same issue, ACL may or may not be a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks man. Thats fine what you have decided, but trust me, ACL Manager saved my butt way too many times, so I trust it immensely. Not to mention cases when I had no chance to start from scratch, because I've been updating heavy visited live sites. So, this extension have always offered if not quick fix, but at least peace of mind, knowing that everything under the hood, on the lowest level of CMS, is working as it should.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was down to a problem with a PDO database <strike>file</strike> MySQL driver, which is why it wasn't replicated on my other 3.5.0 site, which was using MySql.

There is a fix here, or it should be patched in the next update:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/9610