# problem with joomla 3.5 menus

Tags: menu-item, joomla-3.5

After installing Joomla 3.5, I started adding some menu items, but after saving them, there seems to be a problem with the menu level.

After adding another menu item, the level changes from **8** to **11**.

Has anyone some across this problem before that could shed some light?

[image: first]

[image: secound]

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Please check my answer to Q http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15860/joomla-turns-all-menu-items-to-sub-sub-menu-items-when-adding-a-new-one/15862#15862

Comment: tnx @Mikan but i cant bought this plugin because of limits to my country about international payments is there away to fix it with out other extensions ?

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I know how that feels, been in similar situation in my country few years ago... No, unfortunately there is no similar extension at all, not just free...

Comment: :( , @mikan are you know a way with programming or changing in codes of joomla ? or database ?